# Getting error C3352: 'Add' : the specified function does not match the delegate type 'void (System::Object ^)' 

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, datagridview, delegates

I'm trying to implement a data grid view control and I get the this error: error C3352: 'Add' : the specified function does not match the delegate type 'int (System::Object ^)'

when I try to do this:

```
delegate int AddDelegateTest(System::Object^);

if(ColourGridViewControl->InvokeRequired)
    {
         array<String^>^row1 = gcnew array<String^> {"red","blue","yellow","green","white"};

         //This gives an error
         AddDelegateTest^ hTest = gcnew AddDelegateTest(ColourGridViewControl->Rows, &System::Windows::Forms::DataGridViewRowCollection::Add); 

         this->BeginInvoke(hTest,row1);
     }
```

I'm not really sure whats causing this error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Ok, so I changed my delegate declaration to:
     delegate int AddDelegateTest(cli::array^);
The error goes away but I get a runtime exception now:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException' occurred in mscorlib.dll  Additional information: Parameter count mismatch.

Does anyone know why this happens?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    delegate int AddDelegateTest(array<Object^>^);
    ...
        array<String^>^ row1 = gcnew array<String^> {"red","blue","yellow","green","white"};
        AddDelegateTest^ hTest = gcnew AddDelegateTest(dataGridView1->Rows, 
            &System::Windows::Forms::DataGridViewRowCollection::Add); 
        array<Object^>^ args = gcnew array<Object^> { row1 };
        this->BeginInvoke(hTest, args);
```